# How to store list of database items in HTML?

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I'm working on a project using Django framework. I'm displaying to user table with data. Next to each row there is an "Edit" button. When user clicks this button, in one of cells of the row select box appears with usernames. Currently to feed this HTML select element with options, I store all usernames in data attribute of div element and when user clicks this "Edit" button, I get the list from this data attribute to create options. It seems to me that it isn't the proper solution. Are there any better solutions to store usernames in a page so I can get them when needed?
Current code:

```
<div id="usernames" data-usernames="{{users |safe}}" class="hidden"></div>
(...)

var divWithUsernames = document.getElementById("usernames");
var usernames = (divWithUsernames.getAttribute("data-usernames").replace(/&(l|g|quo)t;/g, function (a, b) {
    return {
        l: '<',
        g: '>',
        quo: '"'
    }[b];
}));
for (var i = 0; i < usernames.length; i++) {
    var val = usernames[i];
    var option = $("<option />", {value: val, text: val});
    option.appendTo($select);
}
```

Comment: And why don't you create a form with select element, set for it in CSS `display: none;` and when the user clicks 'Edit' change that with jQuery to `display: block;` (or `display: block-inline;`)? You're making your life to complicated.

Comment: Good point. I haven't thought about it. Thanks for advice.
EDIT: Rows are created after page loads, because they are drew by jquery datatables in deferred manner, it makes impossible to create form earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use ajax to load the json data and populate the select list any time I need.

It would look something like this:

### JSON "users.json"

```
[{ user: "bob", age: 40 }]
```

### jQuery:

```
$.get("users.json",function(data){
  $.each(data,function(i,v){
     $("<option/>").html(v.user).val(v.age).appendTo("select#usernames");
  });
});
```

Comment: But doesn't it make unnecessary amount of HTTP requests? It will cause to call HTTP request every time a user want to edit a row and he may edit several rows, each time loading the same data with AJAX.

Comment: You don't have to load the json data on every request if it doesn't change, just on every page load.  The same as loading a javascript object to your page, and using that to populate the list anytime you need to.